# FFT What are the other frequencies when a single piano note is played

Tags: python, scipy, fft, wav, piano

I have recorded a piano note G#4/ Ab4 in wav file.
I am using the scipy read to read this wav file and plot the FFT, i was expecting just the dominant frequency of 415Hz. The FFT is displaying this frequency but with that there are other frequencies closer to it, which i am not sure why they are seen. Please explain

Original Signal from wav file
[image]

FFT of the Original Signal

[image]

The peak Frequency is 415.2012138678529 and Amplitude at 2271 bit

But when i check the FFT frequency sequence, i also see these values which are closer to 415 Hz

[image]

Following is my code

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack as fftpack
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

def plotGraph(figNum,x,y,xlabel,ylabel,graphlabel,color,isFFT):
    plt.figure(figNum)
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    if(isFFT=='true'):
        plt.stem(x, y, label=graphlabel,use_line_collection=True)
    else:
        plt.plot(x, y, color=color,linewidth=4.0,label=graphlabel)    
    plt.legend()

def exportToCSV(x,y,xlabel,ylabel,csvfilename):
    df = pd.DataFrame({xlabel : x, ylabel : y})
    df.to_csv(csvfilename, index=False)

def filtersignal(x,y,xlabel,ylabel,csvfilename):
    mask = y >0
    signal_with_mask = abs(y[mask])
    mean=np.mean(signal_with_mask,dtype=np.float64)
    standard_deviation=np.std(signal_with_mask,dtype=np.float64)
    third_standard_deviation=3*standard_deviation
    df = pd.DataFrame({xlabel : x[mask], ylabel : signal_with_mask - mean})   
    # print(third_standard_deviation,df[df[ylabel] > third_standard_deviation])
    signal_after_filter = df[df[ylabel] > third_standard_deviation]
    signal_after_filter.to_csv(csvfilename,header=None,index=False)

def setPlotParams():
    params = {'legend.fontsize': '20',
          'font.family': 'Times New Roman Bold',
          'font.size': '15',
          'axes.labelsize': 'x-large',
          'axes.labelweight': 'bold',
          'axes.titlesize':'x-large',
          'xtick.labelsize':'x-large',
          'ytick.labelsize':'x-large',
          'font.weight':'bold'}
    plt.rcParams.update(params)

  
def plotBarGraphFromCSV(figNum,csvfile1,csvfile2,xlabel,ylabel):
    Original_X = []
    Original_Y = []
    
    Reconstructed_X = []
    Reconstructed_Y = []
    
    with open(csvfile1,'r') as csvfile:
        plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in plots:
            Original_X.append(float(row[0]))
            Original_Y.append(float(row[1]))
            
    with open(csvfile2,'r') as csvfile:
        plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in plots:
            Reconstructed_X.append(float(row[0]))
            Reconstructed_Y.append(float(row[1]))
    
    plt.figure(figNum)
    lenx=len(Original_X)
    rlenx=len(Reconstructed_X)
    ind = np.arange(lenx) 
    indr = np.arange(rlenx)
    width = 0.35 
    plt.bar(ind, Original_Y, width, color='blue', label='Original Sample')
    plt.bar(indr + width, Reconstructed_Y, width,color='green',label='Reconstructed FFT Sample')
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    
# -----------------------Read the wav file to generate Time---------------
# wavFileName ="latest/PuriyaWOTanpura.wav"
wavFileName ="piano_Ab4.wav"
sample_rate, sample_data = wavfile.read(wavFileName)
print ("Sample Rate or Sampling Frequency is", sample_rate," Hz")
print(sample_data.dtype)
l_audio = len(sample_data.shape)

print ("Channels", l_audio,"Audio data shape",sample_data.shape,"l_audio",l_audio)
if l_audio == 2:
    sample_data = sample_data.sum(axis=1) / 2
N = sample_data.shape[0]
length = N / sample_rate
print ("Duration of audio wav file in secs", length,"Number of Samples chosen",sample_data.shape[0])
time =np.linspace(0, length, sample_data.shape[0])
sampling_interval=time[1]-time[0]
#---------------FFT of Original signal-----------------------
fft_amplitude=2.0*np.abs(fftpack.fft(sample_data)/len(time))
fft_freqs=fftpack.fftfreq(len(time),sampling_interval)
idx = np.argmax(np.abs(fft_amplitude))
freq = fft_freqs[idx]
freq_in_hertz = abs(freq * sample_rate)
print('Frequency ',freq,' Amplitude ',idx)
mask = fft_freqs > 0
#---------------Inverse FFT------------------------------------
inverse_fft_amplitude = scipy.ifft(fftpack.fft(sample_data))
#-----------------------Graph plotting----------------------------
setPlotParams()
plotGraph(1,time,sample_data,'Time [s]','Sample Data [bits]','Time vs Sample Data','red','false')
plotGraph(2,fft_freqs[mask],fft_amplitude[mask],'Frequency [Hz]','Sample Data [bits]','Frequency vs Sample Data','blue','true')
plotGraph(3,time,inverse_fft_amplitude,'Time [s]','Sample Data [bits]','Time vs Sample Data','green','false')
# -----------------------Exporting Results to CSV-----------------------------
exportToCSV(time,sample_data,'Time','Sample Data','OriginalData.csv')
exportToCSV(fft_freqs[mask],fft_amplitude[mask],'Frequency','Sample Data','FFTDataSet.csv')
exportToCSV(time,inverse_fft_amplitude,'Time','Sample Data','ReconstructedDataSet.csv')
# -----------------------Plot Original and Reconstructed Signal-------------
filtersignal(time,sample_data,'Time','Sample Data','OriginalDataWithMask.csv')
filtersignal(time,inverse_fft_amplitude,'Time','Sample Data','ReconstructedDataSetWithMask.csv')
plotBarGraphFromCSV(4,'OriginalDataWithMask.csv', 'ReconstructedDataSetWithMask.csv','Time [s]','Sample Data [bits]')
```

Comment: This might be helpful to you
https://www.kaggle.com/asparago/simple-pitch-detector

Comment: It is not due to ```python```, ```scipy``` or even ```fft```. It is pure physics behind, I mean, any real resonance always has finite width. I think [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) is the right place for the question `why I don't get a Dirac-function-like spectrum by numerically Fourier-transforming a real-world acoustic signal?`